# How can I undo my bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

I, by mistake, put a bounty on the following question:

[How to use the both JavaScript validation and asp.net validation for a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117137/how-to-use-the-both-javascript-validation-and-asp-net-validation-for-a-control)

It now says

> This question has an open bounty worth +150 reputation from Ramesh Rajendran ending in 7 days.

I did not intend to do this and only clicked on the bounty link to see what this functionality was all about. Now I seem to have put a bounty on the question and my reputation dropped by 150 points.

I would like to undo this? Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to? The bounty process has several steps and a confirmation. Why did you go through it in the first place?

Comment: Because My point's  is decrease !

Comment: Yep, that's how the bounty system works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Oh ! Thank you so much for the link .

Comment: Especially given the bounty reason I'm assuming this was a mistake? If so, flag the question and explain the situation using the "other" option. Maybe it can be refunded. But that's not at all certain and usually doesn't happen.

Comment: Did you want to award yourself 150 reputation points, which you assume came from thin air?

Comment: Important safety tip:  do not use a feature until you understand the feature.

Comment: No . I don't know that . I clicked for  reason is what is the functionality here ?, So i checked that . But now i understand that !! it's okay

Comment: @RameshRajendran Can happen. Just be careful next time. Otherwise you'll never catch up with Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Bart oh thanks .really thanks.. I cached it . But sorry . next time i  did not try this

Comment: **Come on, guys: Stop down voting. He doesn't deserve a question ban because he made a mistake...** (he'll never catch Jon if he can't ask questions!)

Comment: Oh @Undo you are a great man .Thanks for your support !

Comment: @RameshRajendran You're welcome. We're all together in the effort to overthrow Skeet.

Comment: @Undo Rep on meta is different from rep on SO proper; downvotes here don't affect meta rep.  It's *really* hard to get a question ban on meta.  You pretty much need to be trying to get one.  Finally, this question does not demonstrate much research effort; there are lots of questions on this topic, as well as it being covered in the FAQ.  That's an acceptable reason to downvote it.

Comment: @Servy Eh? Downvotes here on MSO absolutely affect meta rep. Or did you mean downvotes here don't affect Stack Overflow rep? :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Sorry, I meant to say downvotes on meta only affect meta rep, not the main site's rep.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally, once a bounty is placed, it *cannot* be removed, under any circumstances. Well, that's not true; Moderators will sometimes remove bounties that were strategically placed only to keep a question from being closed, when said question *should be* closed. (that situation obviously does not apply to your bounty)

I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt, and I have done something you should *never* expect to happen again: I have refunded/removed the bounty on the question you linked. Another user flagged it and pointed to this discussion, and I am inclined to chalk that up to a language-confusion issue.

The main reason I am doing this is because you came here almost *instantly* upon realizing your mistake - not after a few days of gaining the benefit of a bounty (increased attention for the question), and because I think you may have misunderstood how it all works.

But don't do that again, because you won't get another bounty refunded. :)

Comment: +1 for being a [Good Guy Mod](http://i.qkme.me/3u1jx7.jpg)!

Comment: @Polynomial Hey... where'd you get that pic of me smoking a... umm... cigarette...??

Comment: +1, if I were a mod I honestly would not have done this :D

Comment: It'd be funny if you got a reversal badge for this.  +1

Comment: @Doorknob then why'd you upvote?  Did you now learn something new so that if you become a mod in the future you would do this?

Comment: The mods seem to be in a good mood, quick everyone upvote your favourite [meta-tag:feature-request]! (I know it's not typically mods that implement these).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Not sure if that was just a typo or if it was intentional and you don't actually want anyone to go and upvote a feature request...

Comment: @Servy: It was meant in jest. I hopefully implied they should only upvote a feature-request they agree with. :)

Comment: @Servy: Just realised you might be referring to my typo in the tag link. Fixed now.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Upvote [s]all[/s] none of the things!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yeah, the typo could have been intentional, to imply that there are no feature requests worth upvoting...

Comment: @djechlin Because he went above and beyond to help this user even though most people would have said 'meh' and done nothing.

Comment: @Doorknob right so, by your own opinion you should do that should you become a mod.

Comment: @AndrewBarber There's a reason I have >30k rep on Security SE... ultimate ninja stalking skills!

Answer (score 8):

You can't 'remove' a bounty and get that rep back. You'll never get the rep you gave as a bounty back.

**You have to reward it to *someone***. If you want to just get rid of it (I don't know why you would want to), you can reward it to an answer by clicking the <kbd>+150</kbd> button next to an answer.

For more info, see [the bounty FAQ.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Comment: A mod can return the bounty back, though you'd have to convince them to do that.

Comment: @DoubleAA "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty." -- he wanted more *reps*

Comment: @jmfsg Or he had no such intentions and simply screwed up experimenting with the system. It has happened before.

Comment: @jmfsg Hence he is likely to be unsuccessful at convincing the mods. This answer is however only mostly accurate.

Comment: Yeah, everything is possible I guess...

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177534/186381) is why you never say never.

Comment: @Servy Give this Andrew Barber a diamond and weird things start to happen. :)

Comment: @Bart This is why we can't have nice things?

Comment: @Bart Never give a barber a diamond

Comment: I thought diamonds were a barber's best friend?

Comment: @Undo I "undid" that edit. There's no need for it. Your answer is just fine for the general case. This is a mere exception given what most likely are special circumstances. Your answer is not less valid because of it.

Comment: @Bart OK, fine with me. This is not the edit war you are looking for.

Comment: Did you get the Cleanup badge yet?

Comment: @Undo With a username like yours I'm surprised you don't have it yet. ;)

Comment: @Bart Like it? I've got the badge on SO, not on SOm - yet...

Comment: I sometimes wonder how many mods have clicked on it to see what the 'undo' button does