# Is it possible to remove bounty?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties, specific-question

I accidentally clicked on the bounty option on my question and the confirmation box. I lost my 100 reputations. I want to cancel that bounty option on my question, because I got the answer from another source. This is my question: [passing file name to R from javascript using Rook package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478766/passing-file-name-to-r-from-javascript-using-rook-package). How can I cancel the that bounty? Removing question won't help as I want to keep reputation that I have got on it.

Comment: See [What's reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation) on how to get more rep.

Comment: How do you _accidentally_ click a link _and_ confirmation?

Comment: @Oded, unicorn intoxication, most probably.

Comment: Did you ask the last question the search engine of [meta]? I'm sure that it can answer it.

Comment: @Oded He was holding enter.

Comment: Amazingly, this has [happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177531/how-can-i-undo-my-bounty)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: What.

Comment: @Bolt, don't worry, from your username everyone believes you're a mechanical unicorn. You're not at risk.

Comment: To be fair to the OP they did [ask this question instantly after posting the bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16478766/revisions) as in @LBT's duplicate.

Comment: Though they posted a bounty on a week old self-answered question. That sounds fishy to me...

Comment: According to the [Reputation Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2050874/dinoop-nair?tab=reputation) and the [revison history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16478766/revisions) [Will♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) has removed the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cancel the bounty. You cannot get your reputation back.

While mods to technically have the ability to refund a bounty, it is reserved for special circumstances and "I didn't meant to post the bounty" isn't one of them.

You'll simply need to award it to someone.